# MS SQL 2008 - Trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

I am new to SQL Trigger and need some help.  I have the update trigger below and it is working fine -- updating the CompletedDate when Status = 'Completed' or 'Created By Error'.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_CompletedDate] ON [dbo].[ERP_PurchaseRequest] AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (UPDATE(PRStatus))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE pr SET CompletedDate = GETDATE()
            FROM  [ERP_PurchaseRequest] pr
            INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON pr.PRStatus = i.PRStatus
            WHERE (i.PRStatus = 'Completed'
                    AND pr.PRID = i.PRID)
                OR
                    (i.PRStatus = 'Created By Error'
                    AND pr.PRID = i.PRID)
    END

END
```

Now, I need to modify this trigger to perform as this:

1) If i.PRStatus = 'Completed', then UPDATE CompletedDate, and perform another UPDATE query for a different table WHERE PRID to the PRID updated, like:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 = 'Yes" Where PRID = i.PRID (from the inserted table)
```

2) ElseIf i.PRStatus = 'Created By Error', then just UPDATE the CompletedDate only.

If possible, please provide a sample codes. Appreciated!

Thank you,

Comment: So what did you try?  What didn't work?  Why didn't it work?

Comment: I don't know how to separate the update when it is joined to the INSERTED table.

Comment: I figured out the work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't make it very clear what exactly you are trying to achieve here, and you also have not demonstrated anything that you have tried to make it work. I'm going to make my best stab at trying to figure out what you're going for here but I don't have all the information. In any case, here you go. Let us know if it works.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('ERP_PurchaseRequest') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE ERP_PurchaseRequest (
    PRID INT,
    PRStatus VARCHAR(255),
    CompletedDate DATETIME)
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('OtherTable') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE OtherTable (
    PRID INT,
    Column1 VARCHAR(50))
GO


CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_CompletedDate] ON ERP_PurchaseRequest AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (UPDATE(PRStatus))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE pr SET CompletedDate = GETDATE()
        FROM  ERP_PurchaseRequest pr
        INNER JOIN inserted i ON pr.PRID = i.PRID
            AND pr.PRStatus = i.PRStatus
        WHERE i.PRStatus IN ('Completed', 'Created By Error')

        UPDATE ot SET Column1 = 'Yes'
        FROM OtherTable ot
        INNER JOIN inserted i on i.PRID = ot.PRID
        WHERE I.PRStatus = 'Completed'
    END
END
```

Comment: Thanks @David. That works! Clarification: As you mentioned in the beginning that I am new to trigger.  The Update/Join with INSERTED table technique I learned from another thread. I did try and actually stuck that's why I came here for help. I wouldn't just post without trying first. Anyhow, thanks again.